# 500 ошибка AJAX WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

Пытаюсь реализовать ajax запрос на WordPress поиск на сайте, но при отправке запроса вылетает ошибка 500, не понимаю в чем проблема.

JS код:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.search_form input[name="s"]').on('keyup', function () {
        var search = $('.search_form input[name="s"]').val();

        var data = {
            s:search,
            action: 'search_action',
            nonce : search_form.nonce

        };
        $.ajax({
            url: search_form.url,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        });

    });
});
```

PHP код:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_search_action', 'esp_search_ajax_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_action', 'esp_search_ajax_action_callback');

function esp_search_ajax_action_callback(){
    get_vd($_POST);
}
```

Comment: get_vd($_POST);  - а что вы тут принимаете/передаёте?

Comment: и вы не json передаёте в post запросе

Comment: А как правильнее все передать? Когда я к примеру передаю пустую строку то я ловлю уже другую ошибку: 400